# Drupal Customizing User Registration Form

Tags: php, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I am newbie in Drupal 6. I am looking for customizing User registration form.

Apparently found that while adding user using Admin login allows registration form to have fields like email address, username, password,confirm password, etc with validations. But when anonymous use wants to register, then only fields like email address and username are displayed.

I tried with Profile module available. But now how could I add some fields (password, confirm password, terms & condition check and receive news letter check box)and behavior (password, confirm password validation etc.)?

If I am adding such fields they are also get visible in Admin>>Add user form resulting duplicate fields like Password,Confirm password.

Could you please suggest me how can I do this? I tried googling but confused me a lot as I am beginner to Drupal.

Comment: This seems to be a permission problem when only registered user see the fields. Check the permissions for the anonymous user for these fields.

Comment: Which permissions I have to set? As I mentioned when admin user adds user then following default fields are visible like Username,E-mail address,Password and Confirm password. After logged out when a anonymous user wants to register using Create new account link then form just displays Username and E-mail address, other fields like Password and Confirm password are missing. So for anonymous user setting password is not allowed while creating new account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference, If anybody wants to customize "Create new account page" (by default D6 allows you enter user name and email address, and initially sends confirmation email with inbuilt password) with setting password (D6 only allows while admin(or user having permissions) logged in) functionality, can use LoginToboggan module.